# Get text from a tag without the rest of the content

Tags: jquery

My HTML is the following:

```
<span class="price">
    0
    <sup>$</sup>
</span>
```

How can I get only the `0` without the `<sup>$</sup>`.

I tried:

```
var total = parseFloat($('.price').text());
```

Thanks.

Comment: `.text()` gets text without html tags so you don't get `<sup>0</sup>`: https://jsfiddle.net/6m48w40s/

Comment: @JonP: you read to quickly my text I think.

Answer (score 1):

> $(".price")

returns a collection or array, you need to specify the element. In this case you can specify it using [JQuery eq](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) function.

```
var total = parseFloat($('.price').eq(0).text());
```

I'm using 0 (zero) since your HTML only has one element with the class **price**

Try it youself:
https://jsfiddle.net/ggderas/Ln7gd74n/3

Comment: I think your solution could be the best one.

Comment: Except this still returns 0$ for `$('.price').eq(0).text()` : https://jsfiddle.net/ab5ne0rh/

Comment: @JonP I believe the OP is having trouble getting the numeric value inside the span element, not considering other span children below that zero

Comment: Well in that case the code he supplied works as is: https://jsfiddle.net/akw9unha/ . And then there is the question as posed "Get text from a tag without the rest of the content"

Answer (score 1):

you can get it easily by splitting like below

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<span class="price">
    0
    <sup>$</sup>
</span>


</body>


<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
  var thePricewith_$ = $(".price").text(); // get the text
  var splitted = thePricewith_$.split("$"); // split it from dollar sign

  var onlyPrice = splitted[0]; // this gives the price text
  var dollarSign = splitted[1]; // this gives the dollar sign
  alert("price without dollar sign : "+ onlyPrice) // print only the price

//additional, if you want to convert it to int and use it do it like this
//   var piceInt = parseInt(onlyPrice)
//   alert(piceInt+5)


 });

</script>


</html>
```

- and also you cane convert it to int and use it like in the comment. hope this will help to you.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
var price = $('.price').contents().map(function() {
                if (this.nodeType == 3 && this.textContent.trim() != '') return Number(this.textContent);
        }).get().join();

console.log(price);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="price">
    0
    <sup>$</sup>
</span>
```

Comment: I think it's a beautiful piece of code but it's too hard for only remove what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Get the `innerHTML` and remove anything inside tags:

```js
var text = document.getElementsByClassName('price')[0].innerHTML.replace(/<.*>.*<\/.*?>/g, '');
console.log(text);
```

```html
<body>
  <span class="price">
    0
    <sup>$</sup>
</span>
  <?body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that there is only one object with a class of `price` and that you want to ignore any text that is in a child node...

```js
var total = parseFloat($('.price')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
console.log(total);
console.log($('.price')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="price">
    0<sup>$</sup>
</span>
```

This also works without jquery with a slight modification:

```
var total = parseFloat(document.getElementsByClassName('price')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
```